# Is there a way to make a Wix website optimized for SEO without using custom domain?

Tags: velo

I don't know whether or not this is on-topic... I have set up a [Wix website](https://one-enterprisestec.wixsite.com/index) so that I can have a forum for my [HTML website](https://oneenterprisestech.github.io), and I want the Wix website to be found on Google *without* paying for premium. How can I enable SEO without paying money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this answers your question.

## According to Wix, Yes you can rank your free website:

> "We guarantee that all of your site content can be crawled and indexed by search engines (e.g. Google and Bing) whether you have a Premium site or not." [Referring Article](https://support.wix.com/en/article/enabling-search-engines-eg-google-to-index-your-site)

### Using GitHub Page + Forms

You mentioned wanting Wix for a contact form. Here are some alternative ways to get a contact form on your GitHub Page

1. Netlify [Contact Form + GitHub Page](https://www.hywel.me/sites/2021/11/15/website-page-with-contact-form-using-html-github-and-netlify.html)  via hywel
2. Use a strong Call to Action (CTA) with a link to a form like Google Forms, Typeform, MailChimp etc

### Steps to Rank Your Free Wix Website

Increase the page rank and SEO without paying for Wix.

1. Use the Wix Verification section to claim ownership.

   - Dashboard > SEO Tools > Site Verification
   - *You can't use the wizard in "Step 1: Get your homepage ready for Google Search".*
   - When you read about using GSC, look at the Google documentation or recent content (last year or few years).
2. Fill out the meta data for each page.

   - [Wix SEO for ADI editor](https://support.wix.com/en/article/adi-setting-up-your-page-seo)
   - [Free Wix Site SEO](https://support.wix.com/en/article/verifying-your-site-on-search-engines-9255141#free-wix-site-user)
   - Read more online about this
3. Give your images relevant descriptive names.
4. Use an online image compression tool to reduce the file size of your images before uploading.

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt seo console in Wix, but I think you might need a paid plan. From there, they guide you to setup your meta tags, headlines, content, and meta description.